# Why do some Talend ESB (7.0.1) routes with nested Talend Jobs fail to build?

Tags: talend

I have a project with several routes, most of which use Talend Jobs, some of which use jobs that have use tRunJob to call sub-jobs.

This project all worked fine in 6.5, but in 7.0.1 some of the routes do not build. (They compile fine if running in the studio)

Looking at the `lastGenerated.log` files for the routes, there is a step which installs the `routeName_jobName` component for routes that work. However for the ones that don't work it is actually installing `routeName_subJobName` and then complaining a few lines later that it can't find `routeName_jobName`.

There is nothing in the route referencing the `subJobName` directly, so I don't see why Talend is doing this.

There is no error message generated when building the routes that don't work - it just processes for a while then closes the build window having not built the .kar file.

Is there a way of getting better logging from Talend so I can figure out why it is unhappy building these routes?

Comment: Having done some more digging, I think that there is a problem in the way Talend is building the pom-feature.xml file, since it seems to complain that there are two plugin entries with the same artifact_id, so I am presuming that it is only executing the last one (the first being overwritten?). The problem is I don't understand Maven sufficiently to solve this.

Comment: I don't know if you resolved this; but it seems like a bug. Did you try posting on Talend forums ?

Comment: Hi - yes - but I've not had any solution - it would appear to be a bug, and so I have reported it but no activity recorded against it yet... :-(